# Why accuracy stays zero in Keras LSTM while other metrics improve when training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have constructed a LSTM model for binary text classification problem. Here the labels are one hot encoded. Following is my constructed model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=dictionary_length, output_dim=60, input_length=max_word_count))
model.add(LSTM(600))
model.add(Dense(units=max_word_count, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.04), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.015)))
model.add(Dense(units=max_word_count, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))

adam_optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, decay=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam_optimizer, 
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(), metrics.AUC(), metrics.Precision(), metrics.Recall()])
```

When I fit this model the accuracy stays 0 all the time but other matrices get improved. What is the issue here?

```
Epoch 1/3
94/94 [==============================] - 5s 26ms/step - loss: 3.4845 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - auc_4: 0.7583 - precision_4: 0.7251 - recall_4: 0.7251
Epoch 2/3
94/94 [==============================] - 2s 24ms/step - loss: 0.4772 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - auc_4: 0.9739 - precision_4: 0.9249 - recall_4: 0.9249
Epoch 3/3
94/94 [==============================] - 3s 27ms/step - loss: 0.1786 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - auc_4: 0.9985 - precision_4: 0.9860 - recall_4: 0.9860
```

Comment: I would recommend using a single neuron in the last layer with 'sigmoid' activation if your problem is binary classification. This has nothing to do with your question and is just advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need CategoricalAccuracy : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/CategoricalAccuracy to mesuring the accuracy of this problem.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam_optimizer, 
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(), metrics.AUC(), metrics.Precision(), metrics.Recall()])
```